# java custom exception first try

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write a custom exception that finds empty fields when inputting data using a GUI and jtextfield. This is my first time really dealing with exceptions and writing one so i am unsure what to do. The code below is what i have been able to figure out so far and it does not work. My question would be does anyone have any pointers or advance that could point me in the right direction to finish this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PersonFrame extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static LinkedList<Person> listOfObjects = new LinkedList<Person>(); 
JTextField fName;
JTextField lName;
JTextField Height;


public PersonFrame()
{
    setTitle("Person");
    setSize(200, 130);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
    add(new JLabel("First Name"));
    fName = new JTextField();
    add(fName);
    add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
    lName = new JTextField();
    add(lName);
    add(new JLabel("Height"));
    Height = new JTextField();
    add(Height);
    JButton jbtSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    add(jbtSubmit);
    add(jbtCancel);
    SubmitListenerClass listener1 = new SubmitListenerClass();
    CancelListenerClass listener2 = new CancelListenerClass();
    jbtSubmit.addActionListener(listener1);
    jbtCancel.addActionListener(listener2);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void CloseWindow()
{
    this.setVisible(false);
}
public Person SubmitData()
{
    String fn = fName.getText();
    String ln = lName.getText();
    String h = Height.getText();
    int h1 = 0; 
    if(!(h.equals(""))){
    h1 = Integer.parseInt(Height.getText());    
    }   
    Person p = new Person(fn, ln, h1);
    int i = OneMissingFieldException(p);
    if(i == 1);
    System.out.println(p);

    return p;
    }


public void OutputList() throws IOException
{
    if(listOfObjects.peekFirst()!=null)
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("outputp.txt") );
        Object[] pa = listOfObjects.toArray();
        pw.println("Person");
        for(int x = 0; x<pa.length; x++)
        {
            pw.println(pa[x]);
            pw.println("");
        }
        pw.close();
    }
 }

class CancelListenerClass implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    CloseWindow();
  }
}
 class SubmitListenerClass implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


      listOfObjects.add(SubmitData());
    CloseWindow();

}
}

public int OneMissingFieldException(Person p) extends Exception
{
    System.out.println("one");
    String fName = ((Person) p).getFName();
    String lName = ((Person) p).getFName(); 
    int height = ((Person) p).getHeight();  
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("two");
    if(fName == "" || fName == null || fName == " ");
        throw new MissingFieldException();

    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a first name.");
        return 0;
    }

    try 
    {
    if(lName == "" || lName == null || lName == " ")

        throw new MissingFieldException();          
    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a last name." + mfe);
        return 0;
    }

    try 
    {

    if(height ==  0 )

        throw new MissingFieldException();
    }
    catch(MissingFieldException mfe){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a height." + mfe);
    return 0;
    }

return 1;

}
```

After working on it for a little while this is what I have. Just wondering if I am going in the right direction.

```
public Person SubmitData()
{
    Person p = null;
    try{
    String fn = fName.getText();
    String ln = lName.getText();
    String h = Height.getText();
    int h1 = 0; 
    if(!(h.equals(""))){
    h1 = Integer.parseInt(Height.getText());    
    p = new Person(fn, ln, h1);
    checkForMissingFields(p);
    }   

    }
    catch(MissingFieldException e){
    }


    System.out.println(p);

    return p;
    }

  public class MissingFieldException extends Exception {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String args){}
public MissingFieldException() { } 
public MissingFieldException( String msg ) {
      super( msg );
 }
public void checkForMissingFields( Object o ) throws MissingFieldException {
int i =OneMissingFieldException(o);
if(i == 1)
    throw new MissingFieldException();

 }


public static int OneMissingFieldException(Object o)
{
    if (o instanceof Person)
{
        String fName = ((Person) o).getFName();
        String lName = ((Person) o).getFName(); 
        int height = ((Person) o).getHeight();


        if(fName == "" || fName == null || fName == " "){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a first name.");  
            return 1;
        }


        if(lName == "" || lName == null || lName == " "){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a last name.");
            return 1;
        }

        if(height == 0)     {       
            System.out.println("You did not enter a height.");
            return 1;           
        }
        return 0;
}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating methods and classes in the line below.

```
public int OneMissingFieldException(Person p) extends Exception
{ ... }
```

You need two different constructs.

Here's a basic custom exception class:

```
public static class MissingFieldException extends Exception {
     public MissingFieldException() { } 
     public MissingFieldException( String msg ) {
          super( msg );
     }
}
```

And here's a method that can throw an exception:

```
 public void checkForMissingFields( Person p ) throws MissingFieldException {
      ...
 }
```

You can call this method without checking a return value. This is what exceptions are *for*. You can detect when an exception is thrown with a catch block.

```
public Person submitData() {
    Person p = null;
    try {
       p = ...;
       checkForMissingFields( p );
       ...
    }
    catch ( MissingFieldException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to stackoverflow. If you consider this the best answer, you can click the checkmark next to it. You can upvote any answers you find useful, anywhere, by clicking the up-arrow next to the answer.